# How do I change the format of a dictionary to value1;key1; in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, save

I'm trying to change the format of a dictionary to

```
value1;key1;
value2;key2;
value3;key3;
valuen;keyn;
```

and to save it to a text file.

I also want to be able to load the text file and convert it back to a dictionary. Also, the values and keys should be on the next row under each other but I couldn't make it look like that here.

I tried to convert both keys and values to separate lists and put them together but I didn't get anywhere. Also tried other methods I found on StackOverflow but I couldn't get anything to work and now I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Are you set on that format? Using `json.dump()` would allow you to easily save to a file, as well as load back into a dictionary

Comment: Yes, it has to be in that format.

Comment: Should every line go `value;key;` or should the lines go `value;` then `key;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
dct = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k, v in dct.items():
        f.write('{};{};\n'.format(v, k))
```

Output:

```
value1;key1;
value2;key2;
value3;key3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already opened your output file as f_out:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    f_out.write('{};{};\n'.format(value, key))
```

will give you the desired output. Reading it back in is also easy:

```
for line in f_in:
    my_list = line.split(';')
    my_dict[my_list[1]] = my_list[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
# Writing
D = {"K1" : "V1", "K2" : "V2", "K3" : "V3"}
f = open("temp.txt", "w")
for k in D:
   tempStr = k+";"+D[k]+";\n"
   f.write(tempStr)

f.close()

# Reading
f = open("temp.txt", "r")
t1 = f.read().split()
D2 = dict()
for i in t1:    
    k, v, _ = i.split(";")
    D2[k] = v

f.close()
print(D2["K2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need something to read such a source text file, you can use this:

```
source = "source.txt"

def readFile(source):
    d = dict()
    with open(source) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for line in data:
            l = line.split(";")
            key, value = l[0], l[1]
            d[key] = value
        return d

dictionaryFromFile = readFile(source)
```